# display job-queue worker tasks synchronously in webpage

Tags: asynchronous, flask, tornado, beanstalkd, job-queue

I have a asynchronous task in RQ-worker to download files from the internet, i want to monitor the progress in a webpage, i searched over internet and can not find any methods to synchronously display the progress or task states.

there's a way that is, i save the RQ-worker states in mysql, every time when my job-queue changed state,update row in mysql, in html webpage, set a timer, request the api every one or two seconds, and then refresh the status div.

I just want to know is there any other methods more elegant to solve this problem?

Comment: If it works then it sound good :) Maybe use Redis for results rather than MySQL to speed up the process

Comment: @JoeDoherty you mean there isn't other ways except html client fetch result every time? any ways just like "keep a long live connection" or "tornado async updates" or blah blah other magic methods? :P